# How to get COUNT value of unique ID's only ONCE in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, calculation

I have a data set where the rows have an **ID** column, sometimes there are duplicates of the **IDs** which is causing an inflated number when applying a `COUNT()` calculation. I need to only count unique items in this list but `COUNTD()` does not work.

When trying to use `COUNTD()` it gives this error: cannot blend secondary data source because one or more fields use an unsupported aggregation when hovering over the Measures because it is now red.

I've tried using `COUNTD()`

```
ID First  Last
1  Jim    Carrey
1  Jim    Carrey
2  Liam   Neeson
3  Wynona Ryder


COUNT([ID]) = 4
COUNTD([ID]) results in error
```

COUNTD seems to be the only calc function that identifies unique items but it is not returning anything

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that ID is type string (next to the variable, make sure it has 'abc' next to it instead of #) and retry your function... Tableau could be confused about trying to get a count distinct of a numerical value.

You could also potentially try COUNTD(STR([ID])).